# Is there a way to determine if someone has retrieved recent changes to their local machine?

Tags: git

This question might be weird, but I was wondering if there is a way to find out who has fetched the recent changes to their local machine in Git.

There were a couple of people who joined and left the project recently, and I want to know if anyone who has left is still able to pull the latest changes, as I know it's possible sometimes even though we disable their login id in the repo.

Comment: Git itself can't help you with this as it doesn't actually manage the connections or users, but it might be possible to help you if you explained where the repository in question is hosted (private SSH, private `git daemon`, github, bitbucket, gerrit, gitosis...)

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "no", but given the reasonable expectation of most third-party Git source management tools and platforms (GitHub, Bitbucket Gitosis, Gitolite, and others) would be to *deny* access to anyone who cannot provide valid credentials, I can't see this being an issue.

The extended answer to this is that it **strongly** depends on when their access was revoked.  If you revoked their access *after* some push that you did not want them to have access to, then there is a non-zero chance that they could have pulled that down.

Comment: HI Makoto, the repo is hosted in bitbucket. and it uses a https url. i have tested it myself , i disabled the test account from bitbucket which i created initially to clone a repo on my home pc. now even when the account is not active, i can still fetch the latest code.

Comment: @sheks:  I'm less familiar with Bitbucket, but is this particular repository a public one?  If it's public, then there's no real way to deny someone from pulling code down; instead, it would need to be made private.

Comment: it is a private repo.

Comment: i see this in the .git/config in my project   
[core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = true
 bare = false
 logallrefupdates = true
 ignorecase = true
 precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
 url = https://bitbucket.org/xxxxx
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
 remote = origin
 merge = refs/heads/master

Answer (score 2):

> who has fetched the recent changes to their local machine in Git

You cant get this info directly from git. You might be able to get it from your servers (http servers, apache, nginx etc).

If your server is configured to work with SSH/https so you can remove them from your repository otherwise you can tell if they have fetched the code from your repository.

#### How to clock unauthorized users?

Switch your server to ssh/http instead of http

#### Why cant you get this info?

Since git does not work with user credentials (username or passwords) so you cant track it unless your server force it via ssh or any other credentials

Comment: Git *alone* doesn't work with credentials save for your SSH key, but if your repository is managed by GitHub via HTTPS, you're using a username and password, absolutely.

Comment: But again as i described its your server configuration. You cant get this info from the repository itself